# Extract data for the previous month (Based on current date) in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to build a query to extract data for the previous month based on the current sys date.

Given below is the query I tried building but with no luck.

```
SELECT order_number,date_part('month', created),created_at from order_table 
where date_part('yyyy-mm', created) = to_char(date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE) - cast('1 month' as interval),'mm');
```

Could anyone assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a higher chance of using any indexes on `created` if you use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT order_number, date_part('month', created), created_at
FROM   order_table 
WHERE  created BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) - interval '1 month'
                   AND date_trunc('month', current_timestamp);
```

or even:

```
WHERE  created BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_timestamp - interval '1 month')
                   AND date_trunc('month', current_timestamp);
```

FYI: your original query is not working, because you use a different `date_part` pattern on each side of the equation.

PS: is it a typo, or you really have a `created` and a `created_at` column?